# Some bytes changed when creating String from byte[]

Tags: java, string, arrays

I am facing some strange behavior while creating String from byte[].
I have an byte array which was filled by reading some file content. Following are the specific contents of the byte array.

[image: Contents of my byte[]]

Here contents of byte[] at location 1533 is -99(9D)

Now I create new string from this byte[]

```
String contents = new String(buffer, 0, bufLen);
```

But Now if I again try to convert it to an byte[] using following code

```
byte[] newBuffer= contents.getBytes();
```

Some of the byte get changed in the newBuffer.
[image: Now byte at location 1533 changed]

I don't understand why this happened. Also what should I have to do, to avoid this?

Regards,
Anuj

Comment: What character set was it encoded in vs what you're reading it as?

Comment: Just had similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37202020/5221149). You cannot convert an arbitrary `byte[]` into a `String`. Not all bytes are valid characters and they will be rejected (converted to `?`, aka decimal 63). To send bytes in a String, use Hex or Base64 encoding. Hex doubles the size (3 bytes becomes 6 characters), and Base64 is 4:3 ratio (3 bytes becomes 4 characters).

Answer (score 0):

Provide the encoding for the conversion.

```
String string = new String(aByteArray, "UTF-8");
byte[] stringBytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
```